# MySQL Alter Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to alter a table, and tried to add lat and long values to the database. The lat did fine and is added, however when I try to add the long column MySQL throws an error with the exact same query.

ALTER TABLE for lat:

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD lat varchar(255) DEFAULT 58.388910;
```

ALTER TABLE for long:

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD long varchar(255) DEFAULT 3.666819;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'long varchar(255)' at line 1

Why is adding a lat column no problem, but long is? I really need the name to be exactly `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`LONG`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/other-vendor-data-types.html)  is a reserved word. Try enclosing it in '`':

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD `long` varchar(255) DEFAULT 3.666819;
```

or use another name:

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD lng varchar(255) DEFAULT 3.666819;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I tried 'long', that didn't work. but doing ` long ` did. Why is that?

Comment: @MeesKluivers The symbol is not ' it is `.

Answer (score -1):

Long is default text in mysql

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD long varchar(255) DEFAULT 3.666819;
```

Replace to

```
ALTER TABLE region ADD longi varchar(255) DEFAULT 3.666819;
```